# Where to "securely" store session id?

Tags: url-rewriting, session-cookies, owasp, websecurity

OWASP Top 10 2017 states:

> Session IDs should not be in the URL, be securely stored

But what is meant by "securely stored"?

P.S.: I personally don't find any problem with URL rewriting if http**s** is used.

Comment: The fact is, if you put the SESSIONID in the URL, this could goes to the logs and be write to it. In Top10, Securely stored could mean : in the Session Object in the server (if using cookies). Otherwise, perhaps in an JWT token for example

Comment: Call me old fashioned, but if client does not accept cookies and has JavaScript disabled, then what?